# How does one simulate the setting of a cookie by a javascript function in python mechanize?

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, mechanize-python

I am trying to use python mechanize to login into and to step through a web site whose initial page has a warning that one must click on and acknowledge in order to be able to proceed to the login page. Clicking on the link activates a javascript function that sets a cookie and sends you to the login page.

The html for the warning is

```
<a id='has-seen-warning' class='button' href='/login/'>I Agree</a>
```

and the javascript that sets the cookie is the following:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var agreed_to_cookie = 'agreed_to_notice';
        $('#has-seen-warning').click(function(){
            $.cookie(agreed_to_cookie, 'True', {expires: 365, path:'/', secure: true});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Schematically, my python code looks as follows:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
url = "https:/blah.blah/login"
# Call login page first time
br.open(url)
# but get request to agree to notice.
# Set the cookie
br.set_cookie("agreed_to_cookie=True; expires=Sunday, 08-Dec-13 23:12:40 GMT")

# call the log in page again
br.open(url)
```

How should I set the cookie so that it appears that I have read and clicked on the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've replicated `Set-Cookie` string wrong. Try this

```
// TODO: replace expiration date with your own
br.set_cookie("agreed_to_notice=True; path=/; expires=Sunday, 08-Dec-14 23:12:40 GMT; secure")
```